# How i can create ghost on wavelet or seismic trace and then Deghosting that in MATLAB?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, wavelet, amplitude

I want to model a seismic trace or wavelet and then create ghost on them, at the end Deghosting in MATLAB.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Your question is a little vague for me: do you mean you want to simulate a seismic trace with ghosting, and then apply deghosting?  That seems to be two questions: can you edit your question and to add what you mean by ghosting? Perhaps with a link to a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use [SeisLab](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15674-seislab-3-01?focused=5148524&tab=function), which apparently has an option for that:

> 0,6.1,'s_ghost_response','Apply effect of source/receiver ghost on seismic dataset';

Comment: this script is not available in Seislab